# E. Coli metabolization of paracetamol

Tags: metabolism, ecoli

For my science fair project, I did an experiment on how paracetamol and ibuprofen affected the growth of bacteria. By day 5, however, parts of the paracetamol blackened (image below). I am wondering if ***E. Coli* can metabolize paracetamol** and if so, **what operon in the [K-12 genome](https://ecocyc.org/ECOLI/NEW-IMAGE?type=LOCUS-POSITION&object=NIL&orgids=ECOLI&chromosome=COLI-K12&bp-range=1/50000) is responsible for this.**

[image: image of petri dish]

**EDIT:** I realized it may be metabolizing other ingredients in the medicine I used. I am including a list of the ingredients in the medicine I used.

Acetaminophen 160 mg in each 5 mL (duh)

Other ingredients (33.015873 mL):

- Anhydrous citric acid
- FD&C red no. 40
- glycerin
- high fructose corn syrup
- microcrystalline cellulose and carboxymethylcellulose sodium
- purified water
- sodium benzoate
- sorbitol solution
- sucralose
- xanthan gum

I thought it might be the fructose, but **is the byproduct really black?** Still confused...

Comment: I thin, you are using blood agar plates, isn't it? In this case, it could also be the heme which can cause the black colour.

Comment: No, the medicine I used colored the agar red. I used regular agar.

Comment: Is it possible the dye changes colour as the pH decreases?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that my answer is not a real answer, but this would be a good starting point for some more science.

Several of the questions you might ask and could answer (with some more experiments):

- Does this happen in plates without *E.coli*?
- You have a contamination on the right side, perhaps also on the black part. Could this be the culprit? Only half the plate is black, the rest is (still?) red.
- You used a paracetamol tablet with red dye and a lot of sweeteners, does the same thing happen if you use one without the red dye? A dye would be a likely source, because it already contains an absorbing moiety. It only needs to be slightly modified to absorb different wavelengths.
- What kind of agar are you using exactly? There are many kinds, often selecting for certain types of micro-organisms, with indicators for pH or other colored markers to detect and identify strains.

For your metabolic question you can take a look at https://ecocyc.org/ where you can find a database with all known metabolic pathways for *E.coli* K12. Unfortunately I couldn't find anything for paracetamol (or synonyms) but you could try to see if it produces a colored product for any of the additives.